# IMPORTHTML to scrape Wiki table specific column with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape one specific column from Wiki table (if it exists), using IMPORTHTML+QUERY in sheets, but it doesn't always seem to work. In some cases when the column is missing it still returns data from other ones (instead of empty output), in other cases, it extracts multiple columns. Does anyone know a better way of doing this? Thanks.
See [examples](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kzMsOMg5v_TPykPbTYU8nMNgO3Ip3BKyvWKQu0jehjU/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, for example, how about the following sample formula? In this modification, I used `IMPORTXML` instead of `IMPORTHTML`.

#### Sample formula:

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(" ",IMPORTXML(A2,"//tr[./th[text()='Died']]/td")))
```

#### Testing:

When this sample formula is used for your provided sample Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- In this sample formula, I tested with only your showing URLs. So, I'm not sure whether this sample formula can be used for your all expected URLs.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: thanks, @Tanaike! that seems to work really well! can you maybe explain it a bit to me?

Comment: @Debs Thank you for replying. From `that seems to work really well!`, I could understand that your issue was resolved. I'm glad about it. About `can you maybe explain it a bit to me?`, in my answer, I used IMPORTXML instead of IMPORTHTML. I thought that when XPath is used, the specific value of the tag can be retrieved and that might be useful for your situation. So, I used IMPORTXML. If my explanation was not useful, I apologize.